# Java percentage calculation based on multiple inputs

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm little bit confused how to calculate percentage based on input values (eg: pick for team)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("1 for Team one, 2 for Team two, 3 for draw, 9 for quit");

int pick = 0;

int team1 = 0;
int team2 = 0;
int draw = 0;

while (pick != 9) {
    pick = input.nextInt();

    if (pick == 1) {
        team1 += 1;
    } else if (pick == 2) {
        team2 += 1;
    } else if (pick == 3) {
        draw += 1;
    }
}

System.out.println(team1);
System.out.println(team2);
System.out.println(draw);

int total = team1 + team2 + draw;

System.out.println(total);
```

This will print individually and total.
l want to print for example if all values are picked 2 times from input:

"Team 1 = 33.3%, Team 2 = 33.3%, draw = 33.3%" and so one for different type of picks. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Now, all you just need is a counter to count the iterations and finally divide the score of team1, team2 and draw by the value of the counter after multiplying them with `100.0` to get the percentage score.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("1 for Team one, 2 for Team two, 3 for draw, 9 for quit");

        int pick = 0;

        int team1 = 0;
        int team2 = 0;
        int draw = 0;
        int count = -1;
        while (pick != 9) {
            pick = input.nextInt();
            if (pick == 1) {
                team1 += 1;
            } else if (pick == 2) {
                team2 += 1;
            } else if (pick == 3) {
                draw += 1;
            }
            count++;
        }

        System.out.printf("Percentage score of team1: %.1f%n", (team1 * 100.0 / count));
        System.out.printf("Percentage score of team2: %.1f%n", (team2 * 100.0 / count));
        System.out.printf("Percentage score of draw: %.1f%n", (draw * 100.0 / count));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
1 for Team one, 2 for Team two, 3 for draw, 9 for quit
1
2
3
3
2
1
9
Percentage score of team1: 33.3
Percentage score of team2: 33.3
Percentage score of draw: 33.3
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the percentage of each price you have to do:

```
int persentageteam1 = team1*100/(team1+team2+team3);
```

and the same for the others...

Explanation:

What you do here is divide the price of which you want to find the persentage with the sum of the rest of the other and do this x100

Answer (score 0):

A percentage of a number is calculated basing on the following principle (or at least as it is taught is my school) :
Say, you need to figure out a number percent ratio of another one, let it be firstNumber and secondNumber. Then, firstNumber=100% and secondNumber=x. From that we get the proportion: firstNumber/secondNumber = 100%/x, consequently, x=(secondNumber*100)/firstNumber. That is, in your case, the firstNumber is the pick summary of all teams and the secondNumber - the team which percentage you want to determine. For example

```
//your code
int pickSummary=team1+team2+team3+draw;
int team1Percentage=team1*100/pickSummary;
System.out.println(team1Percentage);
//and so on
```